# Spring dependency injection with constructor arguments

Tags: java, android, spring, hibernate, sockets

I have spring boot, hibernate application and android application for client side. Also I am using `java.net.Socket` api for socket connection. 
Before I was creating server socket like this `new Server(12346);` and everything was good enough. But now I need access to database from socket class e.g. with `@Autowired UsersDao` field, but of course it is `null` because `Socket` class is not visible by Spring Framework. 
So how do I make dependency injection on `Socket` class using port as constructor argument and make `UserDao` non-null?

Comment: how is created the `UserDao` bean? could you provide how the `UserDao` bean is created, is it a @Component, @Service, @Bean?

Comment: @DanielC. it is `@Repository` and `@Transactional`

Comment: @DanielC. also it contains `@Autowired SessionFactory`

Comment: Could you provide that part of the code where UserDao bean is created and how is configured component scan?

Comment: @DanielC. I am just Autowiring `UserDao` in controller classes `@Autowired
    private UsersDAO users;`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `Spring Application Context` from static method and use this static method to load your repository bean in your `Server` class instead of autowiring it.

You need to create the following classes (found [here](http://www.dcalabresi.com/blog/java/spring-context-static-class/)):

**ApplicationContextProvider**

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
}
```

**SpringConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static ApplicationContextProvider contextProvider() {
        return new ApplicationContextProvider();
    }

}
```

And then your non-Spring managed `Server` class:

```
public class Server {
    //your code

    public void doUsersDaoStuff() {
        UsersDao usersDao = (UsersDao) SpringConfiguration.contextProvider().getApplicationContext().getBean("UsersDao");
        // Do your own stuff with UsersDao here...
    }
}
```